# call many $().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In my list SharePoint I use jquery to show information using

`$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo`

The problem is ,I can use `$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo` more than one:

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bib/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bib/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo({
    columnName: "BB",
    relatedList: "ListeReception",
    relatedListColumn: "Title",
    relatedColumns: ["Title","Contact"],
    displayFormat: "table", 
        completefunc: SetFieldsNR
        });

$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo({
    columnName: "AA",
    relatedList: "Reception",
    relatedListColumn: "Title",
    relatedColumns: ["Title","Contact"],
    displayFormat: "table", 
    completefunc: SetFields
        });
});


function SetFields(){
    var srcDivId = "SPDisplayRelatedInfo_AA";
    var tds = document.getElementById(srcDivId).getElementsByTagName("td");
    var Column1Data1 = tds[0].innerHTML;
    var Column1Data2 = tds[1].innerHTML;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[0].value = Column1Data1;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[1].value = Column1Data2;
}

function SetFieldsNR(){
    var srcDivIdNR = "SPDisplayRelatedInfo_BB";
    var tdsNR = document.getElementById(srcDivIdNR).getElementsByTagName("td");
    var Column1Data1NR = tdsNR[0].innerHTML;
    var Column1Data2NR = tdsNR[1].innerHTML;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[0].value = Column1Data1NR;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[1].value = Column1Data2NR;
}
</script>
```

Only the first `$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo` works. What I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Below - Here I am serializing the calls**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bib/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bib/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo({
        columnName: "BB",
        relatedList: "ListeReception",
        relatedListColumn: "Title",
        relatedColumns: ["Title","Contact"],
        displayFormat: "table", 
        completefunc: SetFieldsNR
    });
});


function SetFields(){
    var srcDivId = "SPDisplayRelatedInfo_AA";
    var tds = document.getElementById(srcDivId).getElementsByTagName("td");
    var Column1Data1 = tds[0].innerHTML;
    var Column1Data2 = tds[1].innerHTML;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[0].value = Column1Data1;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[1].value = Column1Data2;
}

function SetFieldsNR(){
    var srcDivIdNR = "SPDisplayRelatedInfo_BB";
    var tdsNR = document.getElementById(srcDivIdNR).getElementsByTagName("td");
    var Column1Data1NR = tdsNR[0].innerHTML;
    var Column1Data2NR = tdsNR[1].innerHTML;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[0].value = Column1Data1NR;
    $('#ctl00_m_g_8b1ecbc0_8438_4069_92d0_34cc9235ab90_ctl00_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField')[1].value = Column1Data2NR;

    $().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo({
        columnName: "AA",
        relatedList: "Reception",
        relatedListColumn: "Title",
        relatedColumns: ["Title","Contact"],
        displayFormat: "table", 
        completefunc: SetFields
    });
}
</script>
```